# Angular ui-router adding hash to url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am setting up a scaffold for an app with angular and angular-ui-router. I have it working however it seems to be adding a hash into my url (I'm running dev on localhost) *localhost:9000/#/test*. When I land on the main page it's just *localhost:9000* and it still serves the main view content. I would like to get rid of the hash if possible.

So here is my setup:

In my index.html in the body I just have my nav and then the ui-view under that:

```
 <div class="row">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a ui-sref="index">Home</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="test">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div ui-view=""></div>
```

and in my app.js I just have:

```
angular
.module('playApp', [
'ui.router'
])
.config(function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('index', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
})
.state('test', {
    url: '/test',
    templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
    controller: 'testCtrl'
});
});
```

So when I land, it's fine, but when I start using the nav I have set up, it adds the hashes to the url, would prefer not to have them if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Check the html5Mode([mode]) of the $locationProvider - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Comment: inclued `$locationProvider` and do `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `$locationProvider` and do `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` :

```
angular.module('playApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('index', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
       .state('test', {
            url: '/test',
            templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
            controller: 'testCtrl'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

I also have an `otherwise` in there as well, so that if it can't find a specified route, it will just default back:

```
angular.module('playApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('index', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
       .state('test', {
            url: '/test',
            templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
            controller: 'testCtrl'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    });
```

Comment: In the case where you run into additional issues and an error that requires a tag to be present, check out this documentation :: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Comment: Or $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });

Answer (score 1):

Inject $locationProvider into your config and set html5mode to true:

```
angular.module('playApp', [
    'ui.router'
])
.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider ) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('test', {
            url: '/test',
            templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
            controller: 'testCtrl'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

Make sure you adjust your .htaccess to handle this (rewriting back to root).

Comment: More details on server-side rewrites at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to `html5Mode`. But it has its drawbacks.

When defining ui-router states, the [`url` option is not required](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/states#optional-urls). From that documentation:

> You might create some child states without URLs, if it doesn’t make sense to bookmark those child states. The state machine transitions between url-less states as usual, but does not update the url when complete. You still get all the other benefits of a state transition such as parameters, resolve, and lifecycle hooks.

If you don't need to provide a URL for a state so that users can bookmark those states, you can omit the `url` option. The URL won't change.